# QSerialPort reads hex values sepereatly

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I'm using Qt's QSerialPort library to communicate with RS232. I connected ReadyRead signal to my readData() slot;

```
connect(comms,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readData()));
```

When i send a string like "Hello World!" I can read all of data with comms.readAll() and comms.bytesAvailable() returns 12.

But when i send "Hello World!\n\r" it reads "Hello World!" and "\n\r" parts sepereatly and comms.bytesAvailable() returns 12 first, then 2.

And it's getting worse when i send hex bytes like (with no spaces)

```
0x0F 0x00 0x43 0x11 0x00 0x04 0x11 0x00 0x02 0x70
```

It reads values correctly but 1 or 2 bytes at a time. I tried waitForRead() but that doesn't help.

How can i read all incoming bytes at a time even it's not standart letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading from the port while bytes are available:

```
if (f_port->bytesAvailable()) {   // If there are bytes available  
    QByteArray f_data; // data container
    f_data.clear();

    if (f_port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) { // Try to open the port
        while(f_port->bytesAvailable()) { // Reading loop
            f_data.append(f_port->readAll());
        }

        f_port->flush();
        f_port->close();
    }
    qDebug() << f_data; // Check the result
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will always work, as you need to have your own way in the protocol to tell if the whole message has been read or not. . . (maybe prepending the message with 4 bytes declaring its length, or some techniques discussed in other answers). . .
have a look at the way this is solved in [Fortune Client](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html) and [Fortune Server](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html), I am aware they talk about `QTcpSocket` , but they address the point I am talking about. . .

Comment: I absolutely agree with @Mike. Embedding ways to check data consistency in the protocol is always a right thing to do. Still, when working with RS232 you often have to deal with a device. You do not always have the chance to change the protocol. I, personally, use simple byte checksums, passing the checksum as 2 ascii characters representing the sum for my data block in hex in the end of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot be sure to have read all data.

You have to collect incoming data in some intermediate buffer and analyse it for commands complying to your protocol definition. That is, is must meet certain requirements like fixed length or particular starting byte (0x02 for instance) or ending byte (\r comes to mind) or a combination of those.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is accumulating a buffer with the bytes you obtain. 
Then verify if it's a correct command(that is up to you decide what is correct) and trigger  the command you wanna do.
Also you should have a timer to remove trash from the buffer.

Let's see with an small pseudocode

```
    static QByteArrray s_vBuffer;
    readData()
    {
      s_vBuffer.append(....);
      bool bValidCommand=VerifyCommand(s_vBuffer);
      if(bValidCommand)
      {
          QByteArray vCommand=ExtractCommand(s_vBuffer);//also removing the part of the command
          ExecuteCommand(vCommand);      
      }
    else 
    {
       //if timeout clear s_vBuffer
    }
 }
```

Other techniques involves checksums , CRC etc at the end of your command.etc